# AWS: PHP Code is visible instead of executing it in virtual host

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-ec2, php-7.3

I am setting up Laravel on EC2. After setting initial permissions and groups,when I tried then I got *Forbidden* error. The log showed following errors:

```
[Sun Oct 20 08:02:10.648091 2019] [autoindex:error] [pid 29325] [client 39.48.136.176:51852] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/my_project/public/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Sun Oct 20 08:03:03.010061 2019] [autoindex:error] [pid 29326] [client 54.163.75.130:53702] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/my_project/public/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Sun Oct 20 08:18:05.310327 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29321] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

PHP Info worked fine when I put a file in `var/www/html` but all messed up when I cloned my Laravel folder and it started showing the code. After adding `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php` it starts showing code.

Below are different **conf** files details.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my_project/public/
        <Directory "/var/www/html/my_project">
                DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
                AllowOverride All
                Options FollowSymLinks
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

*Httpd.Conf* parts:

```
# Supplemental configuration
#
# Load config files in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory, if any.
#IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
Include /etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/example.conf
```

I do not know what's going wrong. I had setup a previous AWS instance with PHP 7.1 and Apache and it did not have any such issues. I am now with PHP 7.3

**Folder Contents**

```
drwxr-xr-x 13 ec2-user apache     4096 Oct 20 07:08 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 ec2-user root       4096 Oct 20 06:48 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user apache      833 Oct 20 06:54 .env
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user apache      565 Oct 20 06:49 .env.example
drwxr-xr-x  8 ec2-user apache     4096 Oct 20 06:49 .git
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user apache      146 Oct 20 06:49 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x  7 ec2-user apache     4096 Oct 20 06:49 app
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user apache     1686 Oct 20 06:49 artisan
drwxr-xr-x  3 ec2-user apache     4096 Oct 20 06:49 bootstrap
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user apache     1458 Oct 20 06:49 composer.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user apache   148119 Oct 20 06:49 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 ec2-user apache     4096 Oct 20 06:49 config
drwxr-xr-x  5 ec2-user apache     4096 Oct 20 06:49 database
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user apache     1125 Oct 20 06:49 package.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user apache     1040 Oct 20 06:49 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x  5 ec2-user apache     4096 Oct 20 07:31 public
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user apache       55 Oct 20 06:49 readme.md
drwxr-xr-x  5 ec2-user apache     4096 Oct 20 06:49 resources
drwxr-xr-x  2 ec2-user apache     4096 Oct 20 06:49 routes
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user apache      563 Oct 20 06:49 server.php
drwxr-xr-x  6 ec2-user ec2-user   4096 Oct 20 06:49 storage
drwxr-xr-x  4 ec2-user apache     4096 Oct 20 06:49 tests
drwxr-xr-x 38 ec2-user apache     4096 Oct 20 07:08 vendor
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user apache      549 Oct 20 06:49 webpack.mix.js
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
~
```

**History Command output**

```
    1  sudo yum update
    2  exit
    3  python
    4  python3
    5  clear
    6  sudo yum search python3
    7  sudo yum list | grep python3
    8  sudo yum list | grep python36
    9  sudo yum search python36 python36-pip
   10  clear
   11  sudo yum install python36 python36-pip
   12  python3
   13  clear
   14 
   15  exit
   16  ls
   17  pwd
   18  ls -l
   19  vim requirements.txt
   20  pip-3.6 install -r requirements.txt 
   21  pip-3.6 install numpy
   22  sudo pip-3.6 install numpy
   23  sudo pip-3.6 install -r requirements.txt 
   24  sudo pip-3.6 install mod-wsgi
   25  vim requirements.txt
   26  sudo pip-3.6 install -r requirements.txt 
   27  gcc
   28  sudo yum update
   29  sudo yum search gcc
   30  clear
   31  sudo yum -y install gcc
   32  gcc
   33  gcc --version
   34  sudo pip-3.6 install -r requirements.txt 
   35  pip-3.6 install stellar-base
   36  sudo pip-3.6 install stellar-base
   37  clear
   38  sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
   39  sudo pip-3.6 install stellar-base
   40  yum search python-dev
   41  yum search python3-dev
   42  yum search python3 | grep dev
   43  sudo yum install python36-dev
   44  sudo yum install python36-devel
   45  sudo pip-3.6 install stellar-base
   46  pip-3.6 install --upgrade pip
   47  sudo pip-3.6 install --upgrade pip
   48  pip-3.6 --version
   49  pip-3.6
   50  sudo pip-3.6 install -r requirements.txt 
   51  sudo easy_install pip==9.0.3
   52  pip3
   53  pip-3.6 
   54  pip3
   55  sudo pip3  install -r requirements.txt 
   56  pip3
   57  sudo pip3  install -r requirements.txt 
   58  python3
   59  python3 -m pip --version
   60  yum
   61  sudo yum reinstall python36-pip
   62  pip-3.6 
   63  pip-3.6  check
   64  pip-3.6 list
   65  clear
   66  sudo pip-3.6 install -r requirements.txt
   67  clear
   68  pip-3.6 freeze --local | xargs pip uninstall -y
   69  sudo pip-3.6 freeze --local | xargs pip uninstall -y
   70  pip-3.6 list
   71  pip-3.6 uninstall certifi
   72  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall certifi
   73  clear
   74  pip-3.6 list
   75  pip-3.6 list |  xargs pip uninstall -y
   76  sudo pip-3.6 list |  xargs pip uninstall -y
   77  pip-3.6 list
   78  sudo pip-3.6 list |  xargs 
   79  sudo pip-3.6 list |  xargs pip uninstall -y
   80  sudo pip-3.6 list |  xargs pip-3.6  uninstall -y
   81  sudo pip-3.6 list 
   82  pip-3.6 uninstall chardet
   83  pip-3.6 uninstall chardet -y
   84  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall chardet -y
   85  clear
   86  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall chardet  -y
   87  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall Click  -y
   88  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall crc16  -y
   89  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall ed25519  -y
   90  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall chardet  -y
   91  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall Click  -y
   92  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall crc16  -y
   93  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall ed25519  -y
   94  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall Flask  -y
   95  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall idna  -y
   96  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall itsdangerous  -y
   97  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall Jinja2  -y
   98  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall MarkupSafe  -y
   99  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall mnemonic  -y
  100  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall numpy  -y
  101  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall pbkdf2  -y
  102  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall pip  -y
  103  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall PyMySQL  -y
  104  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall requests  -y
  105  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall setuptools  -y
  106  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall six  -y
  107  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall sseclient  -y
  108  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall stellar-base  -y
  109  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall toml  -y
  110  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall urllib3  -y
  111  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall Werkzeug  -y
  112  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall xmltodict  -y
  113  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall chardet -y
  114  pip-3.6 --version
  115  sudo yum reinstall python36-pip
  116  pip-3.6 --version
  117  clear
  118  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall chardet  -y
  119  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall Click  -y
  120  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall crc16  -y
  121  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall ed25519  -y
  122  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall Flask  -y
  123  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall idna  -y
  124  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall itsdangerous  -y
  125  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall Jinja2  -y
  126  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall MarkupSafe  -y
  127  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall mnemonic  -y
  128  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall numpy  -y
  129  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall pbkdf2  -y
  130  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall pip  -y
  131  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall PyMySQL  -y
  132  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall requests  -y
  133  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall setuptools  -y
  134  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall six  -y
  135  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall sseclient  -y
  136  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall stellar-base  -y
  137  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall toml  -y
  138  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall urllib3  -y
  139  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall Werkzeug  -y
  140  sudo yum reinstall python36-pip
  141  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall chardet  -y
  142  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall Click  -y
  143  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall crc16  -y
  144  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall ed25519  -y
  145  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall Flask  -y
  146  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall idna  -y
  147  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall itsdangerous  -y
  148  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall Jinja2  -y
  149  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall MarkupSafe  -y
  150  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall mnemonic  -y
  151  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall numpy  -y
  152  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall pbkdf2  -y
  153  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall PyMySQL  -y
  154  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall requests  -y
  155  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall setuptools  -y
  156  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall six  -y
  157  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall sseclient  -y
  158  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall stellar-base  -y
  159  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall toml  -y
  160  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall urllib3  -y
  161  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall Werkzeug  -y
  162  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall xmltodict  -y
  163  ls
  164  sudo pip-3.6 list 
  165  sudo yum reinstall python36-pip
  166  sudo pip-3.6 install -r requirements.txt
  167  sudo easy_install pkg_resources
  168  python3
  169  clear
  170  sudo yum reinstall python36 python36-pip
  171  sudo pip-3.6 install -r requirements.txt
  172  pip-3.6 install requests
  173  clear
  174  sudo yum reinstall python36-setuptools -y
  175  pip-3.6 install requests
  176  pip-3.6 uninstall requests
  177  pip-3.6 list
  178  clear
  179  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall chardet  -y
  180  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall Click  -y
  181  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall crc16  -y
  182  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall ed25519  -y
  183  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall Flask  -y
  184  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall idna  -y
  185  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall itsdangerous  -y
  186  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall Jinja2  -y
  187  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall MarkupSafe  -y
  188  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall mnemonic  -y
  189  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall numpy  -y
  190  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall pbkdf2  -y
  191  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall PyMySQL  -y
  192  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall requests  -y
  193  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall six  -y
  194  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall sseclient  -y
  195  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall stellar-base  -y
  196  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall toml  -y
  197  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall urllib3  -y
  198  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall Werkzeug  -y
  199  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall xmltodict  -y
  200  pip-3.6 list
  201  sudo pip-3.6 install --upgrade pip
  202  sudo pip-3.6 install requests  -y
  203  pip-3.6 list
  204  sudo yum reinstall python36-setuptools -y
  205  sudo yum install python36 python36-pip
  206  sudo yum reinstall python36 python36-pip
  207  pip-3.6 list
  208  sudo pip-3.6 uninstall setuptools  -y
  209  sudo pip-3.6 install --upgrade pip
  210  sudo pip-3.6 install setuptools  -y
  211  sudo yum reinstall python36-setuptools
  212  pip-3.6 
  213  clear
  214  sudo pip-3.6 install -r requirements.txt
  215  clear
  216  pip-3.6 list
  217  clear
  218  sudo service httpd start
  219  php
  220  sudo yum update -y
  221  locale
  222  ls -l /etc/profile.d/lang.sh
  223  source /etc/profile.d/lang.sh
  224  echo "$LANG"
  225  echo "$LC_CTYPE"
  226  sudo yum update
  227  vi ~/.bashrc
  228  clear
  229  sudo vim /etc/profile.d/my-custom.lang.sh
  230  source /etc/profile.d/my-custom.lang.sh
  231  sudo yum update
  232  exit
  233  vim /etc/bashrc 
  234  clear
  235  sudo yum reinstall glibc-common
  236  exit
  237  python3
  238  clear
  239  sudo yum search httpd2
  240  clear
  241  sudo yum install -y httpd24
  242  sudo yum search php5
  243  sudo yum search php7
  244  exit
  245  sudo yum install -y httpd24
  246  sudo yum search php7
  247  sudo yum install php73
  248  sudo yum search  php73 | grep nd
  249  sudo yum install php73-mysqlnd
  250  sudo yum search  mysql
  251  sudo yum search  mysql57 | grep server
  252  sudo yum install mysql57-server
  253  clear
  254  cat /etc/system-release
  255  sudo service httpd start
  256  sudo chkconfig httpd on
  257  hkconfig --list httpd
  258  chkconfig --list httpd
  259  php
  260  php-cli
  261  cd /var/www/html/
  262  ls
  263  vim info.php
  264  ls
  265  sudo vim info.php
  266  ls
  267  sudo rm info.php 
  268  cd ..
  269  clear
  270  pwd
  271  cd ..
  272  whoami 
  273  chown -R ec2-user /var/www/html
  274  sudo chown -R ec2-user /var/www/html
  275  chmod -R 755 /var/www/html
  276  cd www/html/
  277  ls
  278  vim info.php
  279  ls
  280  docker
  281  exit
  282  sudo yum update
  283  ls
  284  pwd
  285  cd /var/www/html/
  286  ls
  287  vim info.php 
  288  python
  289  python3
  290  which python3
  291  pip3
  292  pip3 search stellar
  293  pip3 search stellar | grep stellar
  294  pip3 install -U stellar-sdk
  295  sudo pip3 install -U stellar-sdk
  296  pip3 install -U stellar-sdk
  297  sudo
  298  sudo pip3
  299  which pip3
  300  python3 -m pip  install -U stellar-sdk
  301  sudo python3 -m pip  install -U stellar-sdk
  302  pip3 install --upgrade pip
  303  sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
  304  pip3 install xmltodict
  305  pip3 install pymysql
  306  exit
  307  mysql -u
  308  mysql -u root
  309  ps
  310  ps aux
  311  ps aux | grep mysql
  312  mysqld
  313  mysql -V 
  314  clea
  315  clear
  316  mysql -V 
  317  ps aux | grep mysqld
  318  chkconfig mysql on
  319  service mysql start
  320  mysql -u slv_user -p
  321  sudo service mysqld restart
  322  mysql -u ec2-user -p
  323  sudo mysql_secure_installation
  324  mysql -u root
  325  mysql -u root -p captur3d
  326  mysql -u root -p 
  327  cler
  328  clear
  329  mysql -u slv_user -p
  330  pwd
  331  ls
  332  mysql -u slv_user -p slv_db < slv_web.sql
  333  mysql -u slv_user -
  334  mysql -u slv_user -p
  335  php --version
  336  ls
  337  pwd
  338  git
  339  cd /var/www/html/
  340  ls
  341  clear
  342  pwd
  343  git clone git clone https://adnan@bitbucket.org/adnan/myproject_web.git
  344  git clone https://adnan@bitbucket.org/adnan/myproject_web.git
  345  ls
  346  cd myproject_web/
  347  ls
  348  vim .env
  349  sudo service httpd restart
  350  ls
  351  composer
  352  cd ../../
  353  ls
  354  cd ~
  355  ls
  356  pwd
  357  curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
  358  mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
  359  sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
  360  composer
  361  cd /var/www/html/myproject_web/
  362  composer install
  363  sudo vim /etc/php.ini
  364  ls /usr/lib64/php/7.3/modules
  365  ls -l  /usr/lib64/php/7.3/modules
  366  yum
  367  yum search php-mbstring
  368  yum search mbstring
  369  sudo yum install php-mbstring
  370  yum search php70-mbstring
  371  yum search php73-mbstring
  372  yum install  php73-mbstring
  373  sudo yum install  php73-mbstring
  374  sudo service httpd restart
  375  composer install
  376  ls
  377  vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
  378  cd /etc/httpd/conf
  379  ls
  380  mkdir vhosts
  381  sudo mkdir vhosts
  382  ls -l
  383  vim myproject.conf
  384  cd vhosts/
  385  ls
  386  vim myproject.conf 
  387  sudo vim myproject.conf 
  388  pwd
  389  ls
  390  cd ..
  391  ls
  392  vim httpd.conf 
  393  sudo vim httpd.conf 
  394  sudo service httpd restart
  395  cd /var/www/html/myproject_web/public/
  396  ls
  397  clear
  398  ls -l
  399  vim web.config 
  400  vim .htaccess 
  401  ls -la
  402  cd ..
  403  ls
  404  clear
  405  sudo chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
  406  sudo service apache2 restart
  407  sudo service httpd restart
  408  ls -l
  409  cd ..
  410  ls
  411  sudo chown -R ec2-user:apache myproject_web/
  412  ls -l
  413  ls -la
  414  cd myproject_web/
  415  ls -la
  416  sudo service httpd restart
  417  clear
  418  cd ..
  419  clear
  420  ls -l
  421  clear
  422  ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
  423  ls
  424  cd myproject_web/
  425  pwd
  426  cd ..
  427  sudo find /var/www/html/myproject_web -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
  428  sudo find /var/www/html/myproject_web -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
  429  sudo service httpd restart
  430  cd myproject_web/
  431  ls -l
  432  sudo chmod -R storage/ bootstrap/cache/
  433  sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage/ bootstrap/cache/
  434  ls -l
  435  sudo service httpd restart
  436  cd ..
  437  clear
  438  sudo find /var/www/html/myproject_web  -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \; 
  439  sudo find /var/www/html/myproject_web -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
  440  sudo service httpd restart
  441  cd /etc/httpd/
  442  ls
  443  cd logs/
  444  ls
  445  sudo cd logs/
  446  ls
  447  ls -l
  448  pwd
  449  vim logs/
  450  cd logs/
  451  cd /var/log/httpd/
  452  cd /var/www/html/myproject_web/
  453  ls -l
  454  sudo chgrp -R ec2-user:apache storage bootstrap/cache
  455  whoami
  456  groups
  457  sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
  458  sudo chgrp -R ec2-user  storage bootstrap/cache
  459  ls -l
  460  sudo service httpd restart
  461  cd /var/log
  462  ls
  463  cd httpd/
  464  ls
  465  clear
  466  ls -l
  467  cd httpd/
  468  ls
  469  sudo httpd/
  470  cd /usr/local/apache/logs
  471  vim /var/log/httpd/access_log
  472  sudo vim /var/log/httpd/access_log
  473  sudo vim /var/log/httpd/error_log
  474  cd /var/www/html/myproject_web/public/
  475  ls
  476* 
  477  sudo vim /var/log/httpd/error_log
  478  vim /etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/myproject.conf
  479  sudo vim /etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/myproject.conf
  480  sudo service httpd restart
  481  a2enmod
  482  cd ..
  483  sudo vim /var/log/httpd/error_log
  484  sudo vim /etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/myproject.conf
  485  sudo vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 
  486  sudo vim /etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/myproject.conf
  487  sudo service httpd restart
  488  locate apache2.conf
  489  sudo vim /etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/myproject.conf
  490  sudo service httpd restart
  491  ls
  492  ls -la
  493  cd public/
  494  vim .htaccess 
  495  clear
  496  history 
  497  cd ..
  498  clear
  499  c ..
  500  cd ..
  501  history > history_for_print.txt
```

**Update**

I am using Centos on AWS and it seems that Apache has changed the way modules are loaded. Hence instead of `LoadModule` it now asks to load different `conf` files in `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d`. I could not find the file where I could enable ModReWrite.

**Update #2**

Just checked Modrewrite is enabled by running `httpd -M | grep 'rewrite'`

Comment: You might want to include the steps of your mistake. You can find your previous commands by typing "history"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: What's the filename of the page you're trying to access? If it's `.html` you'll need something like this in your php.ini file: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`

Comment: @onlineThomas Should I paste the content fo `history` into file or put online somewhere?

Comment: @e_i_pi this is not a duplicate. The erorr might be same but the reasons.

Comment: @onlineThomas output is added

Comment: @onlineThomas The question updated.